# Do I actually need to unschedule selectors when switching scenes?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I just randomly stumbled upon some answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923131/555690 which states

> **How memory leakage is solved:** [...]
>   if you switch scene from outside of scheduled selector or there is more than one scheduled
>   selector then you must unschedule before switching.

Is there any truth to that? I'm skeptical because when a scene is replaced, I'd imagine that it is dealloced, and when that happens it is only logical (to me) that it will automatically unschedule any selector it has. **Is there any need to unschedule a selector when you are going to replace the scene?**

I'm using `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`.

Comment: Whether it applies to you should be easy to verify with Instruments running your app. ;) You should not need to unschedule selectors, unless the selector was scheduled for an object which wasn't part of the node graph (ie target scheduled directly via CCScheduler).

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at `replaceScene:` implementation in `CCDirector.m`.

You will see it does not do very much: it simply removes your `CCScene` from an array and replaces it with the new one.

This, if everything works correctly, will make your scene to be deallocated. This will call `dealloc` both in `CCScene` and `CCNode` (`CCScene` base class). You can also check the implementation and see that those methods do not do anything with scheduled methods.

So, it is up to your `CCScene` class to do any required cleanup in dealloc (or onExit, whatever makes sense to you).

Comment: So selectors must be unscheduled manually? That's fairly odd.

Comment: It happens the same when you register an observer with `NSNotificationCenter`: you have to unregister it manually in dealloc… the rule, I think, is: each one be responsible for his own sh… :-)

Comment: Nah, there's cleanup called on the scene which unschedules the scene's (node's) selectors. If the replaced scene's scheduled selectors would remain scheduled, it would either crash (given the scene deallocs) or it would lead to very weird behavior. Neither is very common, and only found in cases where users had a retain cycle that kept the replaced scene in memory *and* some code still running on the scene actually scheduled a selector anew. This is not a guarantee but having to unschedule selectors certainly doesn't fit my experience with cocos2d, not even v1.x or below.